# Can there be a new of adding vectors?

Tags: vectors

Suppose we have a vector v=<a,b>. And another vector w=<c,d>. Now, when we do (v+w), we do <a+c.b+d>. I am asking why isn't there also another kind of vector addition such as (v+w)(We may use another appearance) =<a+d,b+c>?
I'm not saying there should be one. But I want some logics for it to not exist.
Reasons not accepted-

1.They are of no use in the real world-Mathematica has its own vast world. And I know there's many things in Mathematics that have no real counterpart...at least yet.

2.They don't have any geometrical interpretation-I don't think many ones have tried to give them geometrical meaning. It's like *i* before Gauss.

3.One dimension is independent of others- Give me reason why I can't add them above way I told.

Maybe they can open a new chapter of vector addition...

Comment: Do you want your vector sum to be commutative?

Comment: Not necessarily @AlessioDelVigna

Comment: Do you want your “vector space” to have a scalar multiplication that somehow relates to the vector addition? For your addition, if $2v = v+v$, and $(1/2)v + (1/2)v = v$, then $(1/2)v$ doesn’t make sense for vectors that have two different components.

Comment: What this new "addition" has to satisfy? One can define an infinity of operations on the set, but if you don't impose some properties, it wouldn't make sense calling it "addition"

Comment: @10209 A set with a binary operation should have some structure. In $\mathbb{R}^2$, for instance, your addition does not even have an identity element.

Comment: I can't really imagine how assigning a property will affect this addition. I only know it needs to have some geometrical interpretation.  But don't need it any more. I didn't know anything about vector axioms. Thanks @S.Farr.

Comment: It’s not that “assigning” a property will affect your definition of “addition”. It’s that, if your definition doesn’t satisfy certain properties, it probably doesn’t make sense to call it “addition”. Are you familiar with the axioms of a group?

Comment: @10209 I never talked about "assigning" a property. You won't request any property to an operation to call it addition? Then how about this addition: $\langle a,b \rangle + \langle c,d \rangle = \langle a c,b  d\rangle$, or this other one way to define addition:  $\langle a,b \rangle + \langle c,d \rangle = \langle \sin(a^2-c^6), e^{a+3b+c+d/7}\rangle$ ?

Comment: I meant I don't have any idea to give it some property. I hardly have read any. Take the commutative law for example. I only know that means a+b=b+a. I knew only another 1 law, no more than that. That's the prblm- I don't even know any property to give it.

Comment: Well, then it sounds like you are not very far along in your studies. It’s great to be curious and wonder “if” there are other ways things could be done, and what would be the differences. But I think the first step to finding that answer should probably be finding out why things are defined the way they are, such as the properties of the structures created by the current definitions.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can define vector spaces with very different kinds of addition, they only have to satisfy the vector space axioms. Therefore, when you choose a basis $\{v_i\}$ of your vector space, every vector needs to be able to be written as

$$ v = \sum_i \lambda_i v_i.$$

When we use component representation of a vector space we simply keep track of the $\lambda_i$, so we would write

$$ v = (\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n).$$

Therefore, if $w=(\mu_1,\dots,\mu_n)$, we have

$$v + w = \left(\sum_i \lambda_i v_i \right)+ \left(\sum_i \mu_i v_i \right)= \sum_i (\lambda_i + \mu_i) v_i = (\lambda_1+\mu_1,\dots, \lambda_n+\mu_n).$$

Thus the way that you add vectors in components is a direct consequence of the vector space axioms, and does not depend on the way we choose our addition in the vector space in the first place.

Comment: Is vector multiplication a result of vector axioms too?

Comment: What do you mean by vector multiplication? Do you mean scalar multiplication of a vector by an element of the field?

Comment: I mean Cross Product

Comment: No, this is an additional operation, which does not work on all vector spaces (at least not in the form you mean)